# using Tor with Hotmail

Tags: email

Trying to use Tor with my Hotmail account to send emails. Can access Hotmail and all folders but cannot reply, forward messages or create new email messages.
Any ideas?
John

Comment: Are you using the normal outlook.com address?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely a plugin \ script that it's using for this is blocked.
You either have to unblock and loosen up on the tor browser bundle's security and let it run scripts and such (not recommended to be honest, but it's up to you) - or route a email client like Thunderbird through tor and use that directly.